# Making lists of the nth items of different lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have embedded dictionaries within a list of lists such as this one :

```
X = \
[
    [
        {'the_geom': (999,999), 1: [111,112,113], 2: [121,122,123]},
        {'the_geom': (998,998), 1: [211,212,213], 2:[221,222,223]}
    ],
    [
        {'the_geom': (997,997), 1: [1111,1112,1113, 1114], 2: [1121,1122,1123, 1124]},
        {'the_geom': (996,996), 1: [1211, 1212, 1213], 2: [2211,2212,2213]}
    ]
]
```

I'm looking for a function that would give me :

```
XX = \
[
    [
        {'the_geom': (999,999), 'values': [[111, 121], [112,122], [113, 123]]},
        {'the_geom': (998,998), 'values': [[211,221], [212,222], [213,223]]}
    ],
    [
        {'the_geom': (997,997), 'values': [[1111,1121],[1112,1122],[1113,1123],[1114,1124]]},
        {'the_geom': (996,996), 'values': [[1211, 2211], [1212,2212],[1213,2213]]}
    ]
]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are there always only two list of numbers in each dictionary ? i.e. key 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest. No, actually the number of lists is very variable but I wanted to make the example as simple as possible.

Comment: You should accept an answer out of the ones provided so it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
new_x = []
for item in X:
    new_inner_item = []
    for inner_item in item:
        new_inner_item.append({
            'the_geom': inner_item['the_geom'],
            'values': [list(a) for a in zip(*[v for k,v in inner_item.items() if k != 'the_geom'])]
        })
    new_x.append(new_inner_item)
```

Comment: "The number of lists is very variable" according to the OP. (eg. more keys than just inner_item[1] and inner_item[2])

Answer (score 0):

It can be written in one line, but it is easier to understand when the formatting is parallel to the original question. It handles the case where there are multiple keys in the inner dict (eg. keys other than 1 and 2).

```
XX = \
[
    [
        {
            'the_geom': col['the_geom'],
            'values': list(zip(*[col[key] for key in col.keys() if key != 'the_geom']))
        }
    for col in row]
for row in X]
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output, you should `zip` the inner lists

Comment: Thanks. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip together with list comprehension:

```
[ 
    [ 
        { 'the_geom':dict['the_geom'], 
          'values':zip(*[dict[i+1] for i in range(len(dict)-1)])
        } 
        for dict in list
    ] 
    for list in X
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly variable names but it works:

```
XX=[]
for x in X:
    xx=[]
    for i in x:
        ii={}
        ii['the_geom']=i['the_geom']
        ii['values']=[]
        for indx in range(0,len(i[1])):
            pair=[]
            for j in range(1,len(i)):
                pair.append(i[j][indx])
            ii['values'].append(pair)
        xx.append(ii)
    XX.append(xx)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res1= [[{'the_geom':y['the_geom'],'values':[[y[1][i],y[2][i]] for i in range(3)]} for y in z] for z in X]
```

Output :

```
[[{'values': [[111, 121], [112, 122], [113, 123]], 'the_geom': (999, 999)}, {'values': [[211, 221], [212, 222], [213, 223]], 'the_geom': (998, 998)}], [{'values': [[1111, 1121], [1112, 1122], [1113, 1123]], 'the_geom': (997, 997)}, {'values': [[1211, 2211], [1212, 2212], [1213, 2213]], 'the_geom': (996, 996)}]]
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output. The OP output is a list of lists

Comment: @Ohad Eytan Thank you for a note, Correced